# Running sql query in phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I'm using SQL tab in phpmyadmin to play with sql queries.

When I execute `SELECT token FROM users WHERE id = 25` it gives me result:

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6IjI1In0.TFVltm3hcb9TnVGbgdJuY5VfZwdsEXO5zvbZJOYlTrI

When I try to delete this like so:

`DELETE token FROM users WHERE id = 25`

I got error

> ## 1109 - Unknown table 'token' in MULTI DELETE

I'm confused. What's going on?

Comment: Are you trying to delete just the token? or are you trying to delete the whole record?

Comment: Only the token.

Comment: You don't specify a column list when deleting rows, just put `DELETE FROM users WHERE id = 25`

Comment: Check your SQL syntax.

Comment: Dont use delete instead use update as @jundrie answers is perfect.
And I believe, `users` table has other data and you dont want to delete those user's data. @BT101

Comment: Yes yes my confusion is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to delete just the token:

```
UPDATE users set token='' WHERE id = 25
```

If you're trying to delete the whole record:

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE id = 25
```